# Allow downloading images via registry/GPO in Outlook

Tags: group-policy, outlook, windows-registry

As part of the great wisdom of Microsoft, O365 Business doesn't have GPO available so we have to use workarounds.

How do I allow downloading images using GPO but by editing registry on my win7/10 x64 machines? Are there settings that can be changed and then pushed to all clients?

Comment: Do you mean the download of inline images in Outlook / emails? Why is it deactivated in the first place?

Comment: It's deactivated by default when you install Outlook/Office

Comment: The "automatic" download? Or the one when you manually click on "download images"?